# Fix non-manifold object

Tags: 3d-printing

Does anyone have any guides or tips to fix non-manifold objects? This is my object I need to print for someone but its non manifold, tried using netfabb but it ruins the whole mesh. Is there any way to fix it inside blender in any non-manual way.
[.blend file](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/505073609379938337/763058983426195496/mesh22.zip)

Comment: I've had success using https://tools3d.azurewebsites.net/ and sometimes Netfabb Online Service, while the local tools didn't work. Other than that, it looks like the mirror part is really messy (while it should be "straight and simple"). If you could clean that out, maybe you'll get  a manifold object, and you can later add a simple straight mirror part.

Comment: Hey I get
FAILED: failed to load mesh (#103) on netfabb and on microsoft it just says queuing forever

Comment: While I haven't taken a look at your model, I would suggest you try Meshlab.